# Is it possible to query a Knowledge Graph using only Matrix operations?

Tags: knowledge-representation

I am interested in formulating a knowledge graph query in a matrix multiplication/dot product/inner product.

I have found by chance the paper [Variational Reasoning for Question Answering with Knowledge Graph](http://ws.nju.edu.cn/courses/ke/reading/1_variational.pdf) which uses a inner product in the last operation (look the picture).

[image]

The problem is that the paper is not thoroughly explained the process of inference. It's written "we use beam search" but is not explained. Read:

> During inference, we are only given the question q, and ideally we want to find the answer by computing $\arg \max \log (P_{θ_1}(y|q)P_{θ_2} (a|y, q))$. However, this computation is quadratic in the number of entities and thus too expensive. Alternatively, we can approximate it via **beam search**.

I think that there is an implicit inner product structure inside the beam search algorithm but I haven't found any explanation through google.

Can someone explain better the above mentioned inner product?